# Symfony Translation Doesn't Work In Production

Tags: php, symfony, translation, sylius

I have a symfony (2.8) app (Sylius actually) and I'm overriding some parts of the translation from SyliusUserBundle in `app/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml`
(namely, the translation key is *sylius.customer.email.unique*)

It works like charm on local dev env, but gives me the key on production. I did clear the cache, multiple times, and it doesn't help.

What are other possible causes?

**UPDATE**
Gives the translation found in the SyliusUserBundle for English (as it exists in the original bundle) but gives the key in other languages, where the original bundle doesn't contain the translation. So as a summary, it seems that translation files `app/Resources/translations/messages.<lang>.yml` are not being picked up on prod for some reason.

**UPDATE 2**
I also have discovered that the key with the valid translation is present in this file: `app/cache/prod/translations/catalogue.hu_HU.ba674f8d2fd06750dcd7ee5bb021c1b905b518ea.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the keys into separate files:

```
app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml
app/Resources/translations/validators.hu.yml
```

has solved the problem.

*(An interesting question is why did it work on my dev env..)*

Comment: As a possible explanation for why it would work in one environment could be that one can overwrite the validator translation domain by setting the `validator.translation_domain` parameter to *messages* for example. But it wasn't the case (it is *validators* both in my local and in the production environment)

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the fallback locale?

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: [en] }
```

Comment: Currently it is `framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %sylius.locale% }` while the parameter is `sylius.locale: hu_HU`

Comment: try removing the cache the hard way: rm -rf app/cache

Comment: Nope, the cache was cleared in several ways, that wasn't the issue.

Comment: got same problem with 4 keys, work on dev, but don't in prod !?

Answer (score 0):

Try rename your file with messages.**hu**.yml
and if not work change:

```
sylius.locale: hu_HU
```

to

```
sylius.locale: hu
```